# Firebase Hosting vs Storage - Serve Images with CDN

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

I believe assets uploaded to Firebase Hosting are served through the CDN.
Images uploaded to Storage and used/referenced from the app on hosting - those images on Storage are **not** loaded from a CDN.

**QUESTION**
To get the fastest performance, should I upload images to Firebase hosting and skip storage?
Reason I ask is, the firebase docs only suggest to upload html/css/js to hosting, there is no mention of loading images to hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) mentions that Firebase Hosting is good for static assets.  Images are considered static content, just like HTML/CSS/JS.  It's good to use Firebase Hosting for images, but you should benchmark your options to find out what's best for your specific use cases.

Comment: I needed a sanity check to make sure I was not missing something, because they specifically mention HTML/CSS/JS but never mention images.

Comment: Please feel free to send your feedback to the documentation team using the "send feedback" button at the top right of every page.

Comment: Is it possible to manage cache control for static assets that end up in users browsers?  For example: Cache Fonts forever, Cache CSS for 1 month...  I understand I can use file fingerprinting, but wanted to know if there is a way to be specific.  Also, does the Firebase CDN automatically indicate Cash-Forever on static assets?  I found this but it does address my question: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache

Comment: No, there is no granular cache control for static assets.  The only control you have is the ability to wipe out the entire cache of all assets by deploying again.  For dynamic content service through Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, you can control the cache using the headers sent by the server-side code as described in the documentation, which is what you linked to.